# Decoding hex-containing escape sequences in JavaScript strings

Tags: javascript

I have a string in JS in this format:

http\x3a\x2f\x2fwww.url.com

How can I get the decoded string out of this? I tried unescape(), string.decode but it doesn't decode this. If I display that encoded string in the browser it looks fine (http://www.url.com), but I want to manipulate this string before displaying it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could write your own replacement method:

```
String.prototype.decodeEscapeSequence = function() {
    return this.replace(/\\x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/g, function() {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arguments[1], 16));
    });
};
"http\\x3a\\x2f\\x2fwww.example.com".decodeEscapeSequence()
```

Comment: perfect!  i was using node.js to decode nginx logs which use these hex escape sequences.

Answer (score 9):

If you already have:

```
var encodedString = "http\x3a\x2f\x2fwww.url.com";
```

Then **decoding the string manually is unnecessary**. The JavaScript interpreter would already be decoding the escape sequences for you, and in fact double-unescaping can cause your script to not work properly with some strings. If, in contrast, you have:

```
var encodedString = "http\\x3a\\x2f\\x2fwww.url.com";
```

Those backslashes would be considered escaped (therefore the hex escape sequences remain unencoded), so keep reading.

Easiest way in that case is to use the `eval` function, which runs its argument as JavaScript code and returns the result:

```
var decodedString = eval('"' + encodedString + '"');
```

This works because `\x3a` is a valid JavaScript string escape code. However, don't do it this way **if the string does not come from your server**; if so, you would be creating a new security weakness because `eval` can be used to execute arbitrary JavaScript code.

A better (but less concise) approach would be to use JavaScript's string replace method to create valid JSON, then **use the browser's JSON parser** to decode the resulting string:

```
var decodedString = JSON.parse('"' + encodedString.replace(/([^\\]|^)\\x/g, '$1\\u00') + '"');

// or using jQuery
var decodedString = $.parseJSON('"' + encodedString.replace(/([^\\]|^)\\x/g, '$1\\u00') + '"');
```

Comment: I have just one small objection to this. It's just a small edge case. At the end you've added `([^\\]|^)` to avoid e.g. changing `\\x20` to `\\u0020`. But if it's `\\\x20` then we do want to change it, unless it's `\\\\x20`... I'd write `encodedString.replace(/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\x/g, '$1\\u00')`. (The `$1` capture group is an even number of literal backslashes not preceded by a backslash.)

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing to decode here. `\xNN` is an escape character in JavaScript that denotes the character with code NN. An escape character is simply a way of specifying a string - when it is parsed, it is already "decoded", which is why it displays fine in the browser.

When you do:

```
var str = 'http\x3a\x2f\x2fwww.url.com';
```

it is internally stored as `http://www.url.com`. You can manipulate this directly.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to decode it. You can manipulate it safely as it is:

```
var str = "http\x3a\x2f\x2fwww.url.com";
​alert(str.charAt(4));  // :
alert("\x3a" === ":"); // true
alert(str.slice(0,7))​; // http://
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps: http://cass-hacks.com/articles/code/js_url_encode_decode/

```
function URLDecode (encodedString) {
var output = encodedString;
var binVal, thisString;
var myregexp = /(%[^%]{2})/;
while ((match = myregexp.exec(output)) != null
           && match.length > 1
         && match[1] != '') {
binVal = parseInt(match[1].substr(1),16);
thisString = String.fromCharCode(binVal);
output = output.replace(match[1], thisString);
}
return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2019

You can use [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) or [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) and not [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape).

```js
console.log(
  decodeURI('http\x3a\x2f\x2fwww.url.com')
)
```

Comment: var a = 'http\x3a\x2f\x2fwww.url.com'; console.log(a) prints a normal url.. decodeURI doesn't work for this encoding.