# How decode HEX in XMLHtppRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, xmlhttprequest

I have a site and I used AJAX.  And I got some problems.

Server return JSON string something like this `{a:"x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F"}`.

Then in `xx.responseText`, we have this string `'{a:"\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F"}'`.

But if I create JavaScript string `"\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F"` then I have `"Hello"` and not HEX!

Is it possible get in `xx.responseText` "real" text from HEX (automatically, without `.replace()`)?

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If so, then let the script output the real Hex code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decoding hex string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209104/decoding-hex-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output is at all *regular* (predictable), `.replace()` is probably the simplest.

```
var escapeSequences = xx.responseText.replace(/^\{a:/, '').replace(/\}$/, '');

console.log(escapeSequences === "\"\\x48\\x65\\x6C\\x6C\\x6F\""); // true
```

Or, if a string literal that's equivalent in value but may not otherwise be the same is sufficient, you could parse (see below) and then [`stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) an individual property.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.a) === "\"Hello\""); // true
```

Otherwise, you'll likely need to run `responseText` through a [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) to tokenize it and retrieve the literal from that. JavaScript doesn't include an option for this separate from parsing/evaluating, so you'll need to find a library for this.

"[Lexer written in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823612/lexer-written-in-javascript)" may be a good place to start for that.

---

To parse it:

Since it appears to be a string of code, you'll likely have to use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

```
var data = eval('(' + xx.responseText + ')');

console.log(data.a); // Hello
```

Note: The parenthesis make sure `{...}` is evaluated as an [`Object` literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) rather than as a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

---

Also, I'd suggest looking into alternatives to code for communicating data like this.

A common option is [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which takes its syntax from JavaScript, but uses a rather strict subset. It doesn't allow `function`s or other potentially problematic code to be included.

```
var data = JSON.parse(xx.responseText);

console.log(data.a); // Hello
```

Visiting [JSON.org](http://json.org), you should be able to find a reference or library for the choice of server-side language to output JSON.

```
{ "a": "Hello" }
```

Comment: How it work, i mean  xmlhttp  parse response.

Because i send only one backslash  \x22 
and XHR  return string like '\x22' what is equivavelent the string '\\x22'
I read w3c specification, and i know about utfdecoder 
http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#text-response-entity-body

But i cant find it, cant find how XHR parse backslashes, how not parse backslash? I want to get real value in responseText =(

Comment: @user2773677 `responseText` won't parse it beyond trying to read it as text vs. binary (and assumes the response is UTF-8 encoded). It is the "*raw*" or verbatim form of the response body. So, `\x22` is read as 4 individual characters and is equal to the value of a `"\\x22"` string literal in JavaScript.

Comment: Jonathan, i understood.
it is mean, that raw value will be  must  convert to js view ?
But any way in raw value we have one slash \x0A what mean new line, and js must escape it,no?  Or maybe it happen in JS core, i mean C++ (v8 or smth else) ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just let the JSON parser do its job and handle the `\x` escape sequences, and then just convert the string back to hex again afterwards, e.g.

```
function charToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    return (hex.length === 2) ? hex : '0' + hex;
}

"Hello".replace(/./g, charToHex);  // gives "48656c6c6f"
```

Comment: Well, there's no prior mention of jQuery, but otherwise a good suggestion. :)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  ah, indeed - it's just the JSON parser.  Not that there was any jQuery in my code, either :)