# How to decode this hex code javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just came across a bit of code par my understanding can anyone help me in decoding the code .

```
var _0x98fd = ["\x2E\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x70\x62\x6C\x61\x63\x6B\x62\x67\x2C\x20\x2E\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x4C\x65\x66\x74", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74", "\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x6F\x70\x65\x6E", "\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x68\x61\x73\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x23\x6E\x61\x76\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65", "\x6D\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x6C\x65\x66\x74", "\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72", "\x6F\x6E", "\x23\x6E\x61\x76\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x2C\x2E\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x70\x62\x6C\x61\x63\x6B\x62\x67", "\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x61\x72\x72\x6F\x77\x20\x66\x61\x20\x66\x61\x2D\x61\x6E\x67\x6C\x65\x2D\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E", "\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2C\x20\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2C\x20\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x68\x61\x73", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x20\x6C\x69", "\x2E\x6D\x65\x67\x61\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x73\x6C\x6F\x77", "\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6D\x6F\x62\x69\x6C\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x73", "\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x72\x6F\x74\x61\x74\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x61\x72\x72\x6F\x77", "\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B"];
$(function() {
    var _0x5c8dx1 = $(_0x98fd[0]);
    var _0x5c8dx2 = $(_0x98fd[1]);
    var _0x5c8dx3 = function() {
        $(_0x5c8dx1)[_0x98fd[5]](_0x98fd[4])[_0x98fd[3]](_0x98fd[2])
    };
    var _0x5c8dx4 = function() {
        $(_0x5c8dx1)[_0x98fd[5]](_0x98fd[2])[_0x98fd[3]](_0x98fd[4])
    };
    $(_0x98fd[8])[_0x98fd[7]](function() {
        if (_0x5c8dx2[_0x98fd[6]](_0x98fd[2])) {
            $(_0x5c8dx4)
        } else {
            $(_0x5c8dx3)
        }
    });
    _0x5c8dx2[_0x98fd[7]](function() {
        if (_0x5c8dx2[_0x98fd[6]](_0x98fd[2])) {
            $(_0x5c8dx4)
        }
    });
    $(_0x98fd[13])[_0x98fd[12]](_0x98fd[7], function() {
        $(_0x98fd[11])[_0x98fd[10]](_0x98fd[9])
    });
    $(_0x98fd[18])[_0x98fd[17]](_0x98fd[16])[_0x98fd[15]](_0x98fd[14]);
    $(_0x98fd[18])[_0x98fd[17]](_0x98fd[19])[_0x98fd[15]](_0x98fd[14]);
    $(_0x98fd[23])[_0x98fd[7]](function() {
        $(_0x98fd[22])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20])
    });
    $(_0x98fd[31])[_0x98fd[7]](function() {
        $(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[24])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
        $(this)[_0x98fd[28]](_0x98fd[27])[_0x98fd[10]](_0x98fd[26]);
        $(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[29])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
        $(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[30])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
        $(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[19])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
    });
});
```

I am not new to Javascript and its confusing for me

Comment: *came across a bit of code* via a website which presumably doesn't want you to come across it. Anyway, you can easily [use this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209104/decoding-hex-string-in-javascript) to decode the hex string. Then it's up to you to decipher those obfuscated var names

Comment: Where did you come across that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its scope is so narrow that answers are unlikely to be of use to future users.

Comment: i just tried copying a navbar :P

Comment: Just doing a console.log will interpret the hex for you. Eg: (function(strings){for(var i = 0; i< strings.length; i++)console.log(strings[i])})(_0x98fd);

Comment: sorry but that answer made me understand the concept , but i am using your code thanks for help

Comment: though this is considered 'off topic', I do want to strongly recommend using an optimizing javascript transpiler like closure-compiler.appspot.com. with 'advanced optimizations' and 'pretty print' on, it makes quick work of this kind of code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is obfuscated & minified JavaScript. The array of Hex characters decodes to an array of method names, class names, and jQuery selectors:

```
".overlapblackbg, .slideLeft"
".wsmenucontent"
"menuopen"
"addClass"
"menuclose"
"removeClass"
"hasClass"
"click"
"#navToggle"
"mrginleft"
"toggleClass"
".wsmenucontainer"
"on"
"#navToggle,.overlapblackbg"
"<span class="wsmenu-click"><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>"
"prepend"
".wsmenu-submenu, .wsmenu-submenu-sub, .wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub"
"has"
".wsmenu-list li"
".megamenu"
"slow"
"slideToggle"
".wsmenu-list"
".wsmenu-mobile"
".wsmenu-submenu"
"siblings"
"wsmenu-rotate"
".wsmenu-arrow"
"children"
".wsmenu-submenu-sub"
".wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub"
".wsmenu-click"
```

I also wrote a quick decoder, *in a JSFiddle*,

### http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/1jwb60pe/1/

that came up with this:

```
$(function() {
    var $menu = $(".overlapblackbg, .slideLeft");
    var $wsmenucontent = $(".wsmenucontent");
    var openMenu = function() {
        $($menu).removeClass("menuclose").addClass("menuopen")
    };
    var closeMenu = function() {
        $($menu).removeClass("menuopen").addClass("menuclose")
    };
    $("#navToggle").click(function() {
        if ($wsmenucontent.hasClass("menuopen")) {
            $(closeMenu)
        } else {
            $(openMenu)
        }
    });
    $wsmenucontent.click(function() {
        if ($wsmenucontent.hasClass("menuopen")) {
            $(closeMenu)
        }
    });
    $("#navToggle,.overlapblackbg").on(click, function() {
        $(".wsmenucontainer").toggleClass("mrginleft")
    });
    $(".wsmenu-list li").has(".wsmenu-submenu, .wsmenu-submenu-sub, .wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub").prepend("<span class="wsmenu-click"><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>");
    $(".wsmenu-list li").has(".megamenu").prepend("<span class="wsmenu-click"><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>");
    $(".wsmenu-mobile").click(function() {
        $(".wsmenu-list").slideToggle("slow")
    });
    $(".wsmenu-click").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".wsmenu-submenu").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).children(".wsmenu-arrow").toggleClass("wsmenu-rotate");
        $(this).siblings(".wsmenu-submenu-sub").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).siblings(".wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).siblings(".megamenu").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

The advantage of the decoder of course is that you can keep tweaking it to do more decoding without having to redo it manually.

It is interesting to note that the decoded version actually shows that they have made errors, like wrapping jQuery objects a second time!

e.g.

```
var _0x5c8dx1 = $(".overlapblackbg, .slideLeft");
```

then

```
$(_0x5c8dx1).removeClass("menuclose").addClass("menuopen")
```

It also uses obscure side effects to run functions like:

```
$(closeMenu)
```

Which is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(closeMenu)` which will fire the function immediately.

---

### Working de-obfuscation demo

```js
const variableMap = {
  "_0x5c8dx1": "$menu",
  "_0x5c8dx2": "$wsmenucontent",
  "_0x5c8dx3": "openMenu",
  "_0x5c8dx4": "closeMenu"
};

var obfuscatedCode   = document.querySelector('#source-code').value;
var deobfuscatedCode = decode(obfuscatedCode);

let editor = ace.edit("ace-editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
editor.setValue(deobfuscatedCode);
editor.clearSelection();

// Beautify the code...
editor.getSession().setValue(js_beautify(editor.getValue(), {
  indent_size: 2
}));

function decode(script) {
  var decoded = parseAscii(script);
  decoded = replaceWithStrings(decoded, parseStringArray(decoded));
  decoded = replaceVariables(decoded.substring(decoded.indexOf('\n') + 1), variableMap);
  decoded = bracketToDotNotation(decoded);
  return decoded;
}

function parseAscii(input) {
  return input.replace(/\\x([0-9A-F]{2})/g, (g, g1) => {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(g1, 16));
  });
}

function parseStringArray(input) {
  return input.substring(input.indexOf('["') + 2, input.indexOf('"];')).split(/"\s*,\s*"/g);
}

function replaceWithStrings(input, arr) {
  return input.replace(/_0x[0-9a-f]+\[(\d+)\]/g, (m, m1) => {
    return `"${escapeQuotes(arr[parseInt(m1, 10)])}"`;
  });
}

function escapeQuotes(input) {
  return input.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");
}

function replaceVariables(input, variableMap) {
  return Object.keys(variableMap).reduce((decoded, key) => {
    return decoded.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + key + '\\b', 'g'), () => {
      return variableMap[key];
    });
  }, input);
}

function bracketToDotNotation(input) {
  return input.replace(/\["(\w+)"\]/g, '.$1');
}
```

```css
#ace-editor { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.8/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.8/mode-javascript.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.8/theme-github.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.10.2/beautify.min.js"></script>
<div id="ace-editor"></div>
<textarea id="source-code" style="display:none">var _0x98fd = ["\x2E\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x70\x62\x6C\x61\x63\x6B\x62\x67\x2C\x20\x2E\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x4C\x65\x66\x74", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74", "\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x6F\x70\x65\x6E", "\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x68\x61\x73\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x23\x6E\x61\x76\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65", "\x6D\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x6C\x65\x66\x74", "\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72", "\x6F\x6E", "\x23\x6E\x61\x76\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x2C\x2E\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x70\x62\x6C\x61\x63\x6B\x62\x67", "\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x61\x72\x72\x6F\x77\x20\x66\x61\x20\x66\x61\x2D\x61\x6E\x67\x6C\x65\x2D\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E", "\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2C\x20\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2C\x20\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x68\x61\x73", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x20\x6C\x69", "\x2E\x6D\x65\x67\x61\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x73\x6C\x6F\x77", "\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6D\x6F\x62\x69\x6C\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x73", "\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x72\x6F\x74\x61\x74\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x61\x72\x72\x6F\x77", "\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B"];
$(function(){var _0x5c8dx1=$(_0x98fd[0]);var _0x5c8dx2=$(_0x98fd[1]);var _0x5c8dx3=function(){$(_0x5c8dx1)[_0x98fd[5]](_0x98fd[4])[_0x98fd[3]](_0x98fd[2])};var _0x5c8dx4=function(){$(_0x5c8dx1)[_0x98fd[5]](_0x98fd[2])[_0x98fd[3]](_0x98fd[4])};$(_0x98fd[8])[_0x98fd[7]](function(){if(_0x5c8dx2[_0x98fd[6]](_0x98fd[2])){$(_0x5c8dx4)}else{$(_0x5c8dx3)}});_0x5c8dx2[_0x98fd[7]](function(){if(_0x5c8dx2[_0x98fd[6]](_0x98fd[2])){$(_0x5c8dx4)}});$(_0x98fd[13])[_0x98fd[12]](_0x98fd[7],function(){$(_0x98fd[11])[_0x98fd[10]](_0x98fd[9])});$(_0x98fd[18])[_0x98fd[17]](_0x98fd[16])[_0x98fd[15]](_0x98fd[14]);$(_0x98fd[18])[_0x98fd[17]](_0x98fd[19])[_0x98fd[15]](_0x98fd[14]);$(_0x98fd[23])[_0x98fd[7]](function(){$(_0x98fd[22])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20])});$(_0x98fd[31])[_0x98fd[7]](function(){$(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[24])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);$(this)[_0x98fd[28]](_0x98fd[27])[_0x98fd[10]](_0x98fd[26]);$(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[29])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);$(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[30])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);$(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[19])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20])})});</textarea>
```

Comment: how do i decode this code and any code like this ?

Comment: @GnomeGuy: By hand... slowly and painfully... They do not want you to have it easily :) You could work out each element index and use string replacement to make it more readable. You could probably write a decoder, for this specific example, in jQuery :)

Comment: it means every time i need to decode a code like this i need to do it by self one by one ?

Comment: @GnomeGuy: Obfuscated code is meant to be hard to reuse (read *steal*) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here this can get you started:

```
var _0x98fd = [".overlapblackbg, .slideLeft", 
               ".wsmenucontent", 
               "menuopen", 
               "addClass", 
               "menuclose", 
               "removeClass", 
               "hasClass", 
               "click", 
               "#navToggle", 
               "mrginleft", 
               "toggleClass", 
               ".wsmenucontainer", 
               "on", 
               "#navToggle,.overlapblackbg", 
               '<span class="wsmenu-click"><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>', 
               "prepend.wsmenu-submenu, .wsmenu-submenu-sub, .wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub", 
               "has", 
               ".wsmenu-list li", 
               ".megamenu", 
               "slow", 
               "slideToggle", 
               ".wsmenu-list", 
               ".wsmenu-mobile", 
               ".wsmenu-submenu", 
               "siblings", 
               "wsmenu-rotate", 
               ".wsmenu-arrow", 
               "children", 
               ".wsmenu-submenu-sub", 
               ".wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub", 
               ".wsmenu-click"
              ];
```

Meaning this: `var _0x5c8dx1 = $(_0x98fd[0]);` is this `var _0x5c8dx1 = $(".overlapblackbg, .slideLeft");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

```
var _0x98fd = [".overlapblackbg, .slideLeft", ".wsmenucontent", "menuopen", "addClass", "menuclose", "removeClass", "hasClass", "click", "#navToggle", "mrginleft", "toggleClass", ".wsmenucontainer", "on", "#navToggle,.overlapblackbg", '<span class="wsmenu-click"><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>', "prepend", ".wsmenu-submenu, .wsmenu-submenu-sub, .wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub", "has", ".wsmenu-list li", ".megamenu", "slow", "slideToggle", ".wsmenu-list", ".wsmenu-mobile", ".wsmenu-submenu",
"siblings", "wsmenu-rotate", ".wsmenu-arrow", "children", ".wsmenu-submenu-sub", ".wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub", ".wsmenu-click"
];

$(function() {
var headings = $(_0x98fd[0]);
var emptyJ = $(_0x98fd[1]);

var backdrop = function() {
    $(headings)[_0x98fd[5]](_0x98fd[4])[_0x98fd[3]](_0x98fd[2]);
};

var _element = function() {
    $(headings)[_0x98fd[5]](_0x98fd[2])[_0x98fd[3]](_0x98fd[4]);
};

/**
 * equivalent to: $("#navToggle").click(function(){
 * just follow the array and is positions
 */
$(_0x98fd[8])[_0x98fd[7]](function() {
    if (emptyJ[_0x98fd[6]](_0x98fd[2])) {
        $(_element);
    } else {
        $(backdrop);
    }
});
emptyJ[_0x98fd[7]](function() {
    if (emptyJ[_0x98fd[6]](_0x98fd[2])) {
        $(_element);
    }
});
$(_0x98fd[13])[_0x98fd[12]](_0x98fd[7], function() {
    $(_0x98fd[11])[_0x98fd[10]](_0x98fd[9]);
});
$(_0x98fd[18])[_0x98fd[17]](_0x98fd[16])[_0x98fd[15]](_0x98fd[14]);
$(_0x98fd[18])[_0x98fd[17]](_0x98fd[19])[_0x98fd[15]](_0x98fd[14]);
$(_0x98fd[23])[_0x98fd[7]](function() {
    $(_0x98fd[22])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
});
$(_0x98fd[31])[_0x98fd[7]](function() {
    $(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[24])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
    $(this)[_0x98fd[28]](_0x98fd[27])[_0x98fd[10]](_0x98fd[26]);
    $(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[29])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
    $(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[30])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
    $(this)[_0x98fd[25]](_0x98fd[19])[_0x98fd[21]](_0x98fd[20]);
});
});
```

#### Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0c42rgof/

Comment: That is hardly "unobfuscated" :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, edited...you are right, is just an approach

Comment: need to make a function to unobfuscated