# javascript unescape hex to string

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have a hex code `1f610`, so the format string is `\u{1f610}` with  in display. But how can I unescape it from the hex code?

I did

```js
var code = '1f610';

unescape('%u' + code); //=> ὡ0

unescape('%u' + '{' + code + '}'); //=> %u{1f610}
```

what should I do to unescape it to ?

Comment: Google pointed me to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209104/decoding-hex-string-in-javascript

Comment: I tried but not work, thanks @wapsee :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an astral set character, which requires two characters in a JavaScript string.

Adapted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF):

```js
var code = '1f610';
var unicode = parseInt(code, 16);
var the20bits = unicode - 0x10000;
var highSurrogate = (the20bits >> 10) + 0xD800;
var lowSurrogate = (the20bits & 1023) + 0xDC00;
var character = String.fromCharCode(highSurrogate) + String.fromCharCode(lowSurrogate);
console.log(character);
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

(Also note that `unescape` function is deprecatd.)